# failed to compelet compile android kernel: stop in built-in.o

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel

please help me
i am noob in linux; my device is sony z1 c6903 and download device kernel source from https://developer.sony.com
and download cross compiler gcc eabi 4.6 and gcc eabi 4.8
and i do Instructions step by step from this page: https://developer.sony.com/develop/open-devices/guides/kernel-compilation-guides/how-to-build-and-flash-a-linux-kernel-for-aosp-supported-devices

this errores observed while compile:

```
arch/arm/kernel/return_address.c:62:2: warning: #warning "TODO: 
return_address should use unwind tables" [-Wcpp]

Can't use 'defined(@array)' (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?) at 
kernel/timeconst.pl line 373.
/home/amh/kernel/kernel/kernel/Makefile:129: recipe for target 
'kernel/timeconst.h' failed
make[1]: *** [kernel/timeconst.h] Error 255
Makefile:950: recipe for target 'kernel' failed
make: *** [kernel] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

/tmp/ccitMpzg.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccitMpzg.s:169: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
/tmp/ccitMpzg.s:195: Warning: swp{b} use is deprecated for ARMv6 and ARMv7
```

but in last state compile failed at "LD      arch/arm/mach-msm/built-in.o" and stoped!

please help me...Where did i mak mistake?